# Combining text in C programming

Tags: c

1.
I have a task for C programming. This is the sample file.

```
21:05:56:22:67:00          56
21:05:56:22:67:00          54
21:05:56:22:67:00          89
```

The left column in MAC address, and the right in is the memory. How to make that file into 1 data (make the same MAC address into 1 string and add all the memories in the same MAC address?
So, the result will be :

```
21:05:56:22:67:00          199
```

2.
How to simplify (or trim) the MAC address? Because that contain 6 bytes, I just wanna make it 3 bytes (21:05:56).

Comment: What did you expect us to do? Write ready to use program? This is not a place. If you at least had tried something and were stuck, that's when people are willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the different MACs are a few, then you can store them in a vector of structs with the MACs (strings or long long it's up to you) and the counters. The lookup would then be a trivial linear lookup.

If you know those can be a very large number, then you need a sort of database. If you have a real one, then it's again trivial.
If you have not, then I think a hash table will do the magics.

To trim the MACs, I would convert them into unsigned ints (3 bytes is a number between 0 and 16+M). If you want to stick with strings, [strnicmp()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fstrnicmp.htm) is your friend.